# A complete orthonormal system $\{e_i\}^\infty_{i=1}$ in $H$ is a basis in $H$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, orthonormal, complete-spaces

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm studying about Hilbert space from a book of functional analysis and I just read this theorem (2.1.10) and its' proof.

I cannot understand why $(y-x)\perp e_i$? why is it implied?

Comment: $\langle y,e_i\rangle = \langle \sum_j \langle x,e_j \rangle e_j, e_i \rangle = \sum_j \langle x, e_j \rangle \langle e_j , e_i \rangle = \langle x, e_i \rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hilbert spaces the dot product is closed to infinite sums as well if the series converges. So because the system is orthonormal:

$\langle y-x,e_j\rangle=\langle \sum_{i=1}^\infty\langle x,e_i\rangle e_i,e_j\rangle-\langle x,e_j\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\langle x,e_i\rangle\langle e_i,e_j\rangle-\langle x,e_j\rangle=$

$=\langle x,e_j\rangle-\langle x,e_j\rangle=0$

Comment: Could you explain why $\langle \sum_{i=1}^\infty\langle x,e_i\rangle e_i,e_j\rangle-\langle x,e_j\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\langle x,e_i\rangle\langle e_i,e_j\rangle-\langle x,e_j\rangle$?

Comment: For each $N$ we have $\langle \sum_{i=1}^N \langle x,e_i\rangle e_i,e_j\rangle$=$\sum_{i=1}^N\langle x,e_i\rangle\langle e_i,e_j\rangle$. Here I'm only using the definition of dot product. And now you can take $N\to\infty$ on both sides using the continuity of dot product.

Comment: By the way, how is that book called?

Comment: Milman Eidelman Tsolomitis, Functional analysis An Introduction(T)